# Android resource linking failed on jetified Android MarketingCloudSDK version 7.3.1

Tags: marketing-cloud

```
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 29
gradle plugin version 6.5
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
Android MarketingCloudSDK 7.3.1
```

Using the jetified version of the Android MarketingCloudSDK 7.3.1, I get a `Android resource linking failed` error (see screenshot below).
This error does not occur on version 7.3.0 of the SDK.

[image]

Comment: I do not experience this issue and our SDK has jetifier enabled.  Can you try manually adding the dependency for ConstraintLayout? `dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}`

Comment: That did indeed fix the compile error, thank you. I used ```implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0"```

Comment: FYI, this dependency has been corrected in v7.4.2 of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Manually add the dependency for ConstraintLayout.

```
dependencies { implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:{version}" }
```